# In MyBatis, how to set scope for an <sql> element for re-using

Tags: database, config, mybatis

`<sql>` element like this:

```
<sql id="update_fragment">
    <set>
        <if test="id != null">
            id = #{id},
        </if>
        <if test="name != null">
            id = #{name},
        </if>
        ...
    </set>
</sql>
```

And it's used in a `<update>`:

```
<update id="update" parameterType="MyTableBean">
    UPDATE MyTable
    <include refid="update_fragment"/>
    WHERE id =# {id}
</update>
```

In DAO:

```
Integer update(MyTableBean myTableBean);
```

---

Now, I write a batchUpdate method:

```
Integer batchUpdate(@Param("ids")List<Integer> ids, @Param("bean")MyTableBean myTableBean);
```

And I want to re-use the 'update_fragment' `<sql>` element.

```
<update id="update">
    UPDATE MyTable
    <include refid="update_fragment"/>
    WHERE ids IN
    <foreach>...</foreach>
</update>
```

But it seems the scope in 'update_fragment' is wrong.
It seems that I have to rewrite a `<sql>` which changes `#{id}` to `#{bean.id}`.

It's there any way to re-use the statement without rewrite a new `<sql>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to add @Param annotation to your update method:

```
Integer update(@Param("bean") MyTableBean myTableBean);
```

And then correct your sql expression:

```
<sql id="update_fragment">
<set>
    <if test="id != null">
        id = #{bean.id},
    </if>
    <if test="name != null">
        id = #{bean.name},
    </if>
    ...
</set>
```

So this will add some universatility for you.